# How can I enable Quick-Edit mode on DosBox's window?

Tags: dosbox

I am using DosBox on 64-bit Windows-10 to run a Dos app whose output is screen text. I would like to copy that text, but to do so, I need to enable Quick-Edit mode on the DosBox window. The usual method for doing that on a Command-Prompt window doesn't work on the DosBox window. Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Since posting this question, I have discovered that there is a fork of DosBox created by Wengier Wu, which supports copy-and-paste to and and from the DosBox window. Selection is by mouse RIGHT-click and selection alone suffices to copy the selected text to the Windows clipboard; it is not necessary to press Enter after selecting the desired text. Wengier's version was developed primarily to add Long-File-Name support for DosBox, but it adds other things too, like this feature. It is described in [this article](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/dosbox-vdos-lfn.html), and the download link for it is: https://bitly.com/12jANWF